# How can I add icon images in Listview via Adapter without XML

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add icons to every item position in the ListView. I added text in ListView, but when try to add icons by `videoList.add(R.drawable.mi_icon, "Genel Bilgiler");`, my app crash. Any idea?

**Genel.java:**

```
MediaController mediaController;
VideoView videoview;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<String> videoList;
ArrayAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_genel);

    final VideoView videoview = findViewById(R.id.Videogenel);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lgvideo);
    videoList= new ArrayList<>();
    videoList.add("Genel Bilgiler");



    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,videoList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    videoview.setVideoPath("/storage/A6D3-E544/videos/genel1.mp4");
                    break;
            }
            final MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(Genel.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);

            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add two items to a list of strings, `List<String>`. This is an architecture problem.

If you need a correlation between Strings and Resource IDs you can use a Map.

```
private final Map<String, Int> videoList = new HashMap<>();

videoList.put("Genel Bilgiler", R.drawable.mi_icon);
```

However, it seems more appropriate to create a POJO of a Video.class:

```
public class Video() {

private final String title;
private final int image;

public Video(String title, int image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
}

// getter methods

}
```

And pass this to the ArrayAdapter

```
private final List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
videoList.add(new Video("Genel Bilgiler", R.drawable.mi_icon));

ArrayAdapter<Video> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Video>
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, can u tell me pls video.class enough for other java files, or

Comment: Post crash log.